# Filtered Pagination with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination, kaminari

I set up a website that uses AJAX-pagination powered by [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari). I also have set up simple filtering and searching, so you can browse my list on http://example.com/products/filter?query=blah.

I'm using Kaminari's built-in `link_to_next_page` helper to generate my next-page link. The problem comes about because this generated link ignores my queries/filters, sending anyone on http://example.com/products/filter?query=blah to http://example.com/products?page=2

One solution I've toyed with is to rewrite the link_to_next_page helper to include my filters and search-terms, but this is (as with all things) more work than expected. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according link_to_next_page document, it should get QUERY_STRING from env, so it will keep query parameter

```
def link_to_next_page(scope, name, options = {})
  params = options.delete(:params) ||(Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING']).symbolize_keys rescue {})
```

if it not work as expect, you can pass params yourself

```
<%= link_to_next_page @items, 'Next Page', :params => params %>
```

Comment: Works! It's asking for the next page from http://example.com/products?page=2&filter=examplefilter rather than http://example.com/products/examplefilter?page=2 though, which is not ideal.